# Finding an expression for $M$ in terms of $t$. differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> > The mass $M$ at time $t$ of the leaves of a certain plant varies according to the differential equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}= M-M^2$$
> > Given that at time $t=0$, $M=0.5$, find an expression for $M$ in terms of $t$

I wasn't sure how to start so I began by solving the differential equation to get $$\frac{1}{M-M^2}\mathrm{d}M=\mathrm{d}t$$

Then simplifying, I get $$ln\frac{M}{1-M}=t$$ using log rules. To cancel $ln$ I get $$\frac{M}{1-M}=e^t$$ and then I get $M=e^t-me^t$

However the answer is $$\frac{e^t}{1+e^t}$$
I don't understand how they got that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dM}{M-M^2}=\mathrm{d}t$$
$$\int \frac{dM}{M(1-M)}=t+c$$
$$\int \frac{dM}{M}+\int \dfrac {dM}{1-M}=t+c$$
$$\int \frac{dM}{M}-\int \dfrac {dM}{M-1}=t+c$$
$$\ln |M|-\ln {|M-1|}=t+c$$
$$\dfrac M{M-1}=Ce^t$$
$$M={(M-1)}Ce^t$$
$$M(1-Ce^t)=-Ce^t$$
This gives us:
$$M(t)=\dfrac {-Ce^t}{1-Ce^t}$$
Then apply initial condition:
$$M(0)=\dfrac 12 \implies C=-1$$
$$M(t)=\dfrac {e^t}{1+e^t}$$

Comment: hi thank you so much for answering! how did you get $M(t) = \frac{Ce^t}{1+Ce^t}$? surely if you want M by itself you'd multiply?

Comment: I added some lines hope it's clear now  @Tiffany

Comment: thank you so so much I understand now :)

Comment: You're really welcome @Tiffany

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have done the integration step wrong, you should end up with -ln((1/M) - 1) = t on that line and the rest should work from there. Let me know if you have any problems after resolving that!

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm not sure what you mean? I'm just really confused on how my textbook got the e^t values in the fraction :( Ill have a go with your answer